# Brightness adjustment interval in windows

Tags: windows, laptop, brightness

I have a windows laptop in which we can use the Fn+Arrow Key to change the brightness of the screen. The default interval of brightness interval is 10%.

Is there any way I can reduce this interval so I can fine tune the brightness instead of changing brightness at a step of 10% at a time.

There is a slider in power option which is very nice to fine tune brightness, but I want to do it with shortcut not want to go to power-option every time.

Is there anything I can do about this issue something like changing registry or some other software or something other solution?

Answer (score 1):

By default this is the best you can get. However, there are utilities that can help you achieve what you're asking. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/553906/46507) shows how to configure hotkeys to adjust brightness using [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html).

Paraphrasing with adjustments to meet your needs:

> You can also create shortcuts with keyboard shortcuts to NirCmd, and in the Target field specify parameters such as `changebrightness <level>` (where level can be +ve or -ve). The following commands will even automate the creation of the shortcuts for you (edit as required):
>
> `nircmd.exe cmdshortcutkey "~$folder.desktop$" "Decrease Brightness" "Ctrl+Alt+F9" changebrightness -1`
>
> `nircmd.exe cmdshortcutkey "~$folder.desktop$" "Increase Brightness" "Ctrl+Alt+F10" changebrightness 1`

Comment: Tried nircmd, unfortunately these commands do not work under Win 10.

Comment: @jakub.g I suspect the ability to change your screen brightness is partly determined by the device rather than Windows 10.