# Change Windows 10 brightness increment level

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, brightness

I am on windows 10 on Lenovo thinkpad carbon x1 with Intel(R) HD Graphics. When I press Fn+Brightness key, the brightness increase/decreases by 10. I want to change that increment value to 1. The only way to do this as far as i know is by opening the brightness window and using the slider.

Answer (score 2):

<s>I used nircmd to change brightness as stated in this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/553890/adjust-screen-brightness-directly-from-taskbar-in-windows-8/553906#553906).</s>

But I not sure why I cannot use `cmdshortcutkey` command in nircmd.

Found a better [solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/5u2lvi/brightness_script/ddr4ned)

1. Download and install [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/)
2. Create a AutoHotKey script file
3. Save this [script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/qwerty12/4b3f41eb61724cd9e8f2bb5cc15c33c2/raw/BrightnessSetter.ahk), remove `.txt` in `BrightnessSetter.ahk.txt`

---

```
class BrightnessSetter {
    ; qwerty12 - 27/05/17
    ; https://github.com/qwerty12/AutoHotkeyScripts/tree/master/LaptopBrightnessSetter
    static _WM_POWERBROADCAST := 0x218, _osdHwnd := 0, hPowrprofMod := DllCall("LoadLibrary", "Str", "powrprof.dll", "Ptr") 

    __New() {
        if (BrightnessSetter.IsOnAc(AC))
            this._AC := AC
        if ((this.pwrAcNotifyHandle := DllCall("RegisterPowerSettingNotification", "Ptr", A_ScriptHwnd, "Ptr", BrightnessSetter._GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE(), "UInt", DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE := 0x00000000, "Ptr"))) ; Sadly the callback passed to *PowerSettingRegister*Notification runs on a new threadl
            OnMessage(this._WM_POWERBROADCAST, ((this.pwrBroadcastFunc := ObjBindMethod(this, "_On_WM_POWERBROADCAST"))))
    }

    __Delete() {
        if (this.pwrAcNotifyHandle) {
            OnMessage(BrightnessSetter._WM_POWERBROADCAST, this.pwrBroadcastFunc, 0)
            ,DllCall("UnregisterPowerSettingNotification", "Ptr", this.pwrAcNotifyHandle)
            ,this.pwrAcNotifyHandle := 0
            ,this.pwrBroadcastFunc := ""
        }
    }

    SetBrightness(increment, jump := False, showOSD := True, autoDcOrAc := -1, ptrAnotherScheme := 0)
    {
        static PowerGetActiveScheme := DllCall("GetProcAddress", "Ptr", BrightnessSetter.hPowrprofMod, "AStr", "PowerGetActiveScheme", "Ptr")
              ,PowerSetActiveScheme := DllCall("GetProcAddress", "Ptr", BrightnessSetter.hPowrprofMod, "AStr", "PowerSetActiveScheme", "Ptr")
              ,PowerWriteACValueIndex := DllCall("GetProcAddress", "Ptr", BrightnessSetter.hPowrprofMod, "AStr", "PowerWriteACValueIndex", "Ptr")
              ,PowerWriteDCValueIndex := DllCall("GetProcAddress", "Ptr", BrightnessSetter.hPowrprofMod, "AStr", "PowerWriteDCValueIndex", "Ptr")
              ,PowerApplySettingChanges := DllCall("GetProcAddress", "Ptr", BrightnessSetter.hPowrprofMod, "AStr", "PowerApplySettingChanges", "Ptr")

        if (increment == 0 && !jump) {
            if (showOSD)
                BrightnessSetter._ShowBrightnessOSD()
            return
        }

        if (!ptrAnotherScheme ? DllCall(PowerGetActiveScheme, "Ptr", 0, "Ptr*", currSchemeGuid, "UInt") == 0 : DllCall("powrprof\PowerDuplicateScheme", "Ptr", 0, "Ptr", ptrAnotherScheme, "Ptr*", currSchemeGuid, "UInt") == 0) {
            if (autoDcOrAc == -1) {
                if (this != BrightnessSetter) {
                    AC := this._AC
                } else {
                    if (!BrightnessSetter.IsOnAc(AC)) {
                        DllCall("LocalFree", "Ptr", currSchemeGuid, "Ptr")
                        return
                    }
                }
            } else {
                AC := !!autoDcOrAc
            }

            currBrightness := 0
            if (jump || BrightnessSetter._GetCurrentBrightness(currSchemeGuid, AC, currBrightness)) {
                 maxBrightness := BrightnessSetter.GetMaxBrightness()
                ,minBrightness := BrightnessSetter.GetMinBrightness()

                if (jump || !((currBrightness == maxBrightness && increment > 0) || (currBrightness == minBrightness && increment < minBrightness))) {
                    if (currBrightness + increment > maxBrightness)
                        increment := maxBrightness
                    else if (currBrightness + increment < minBrightness)
                        increment := minBrightness
                    else
                        increment += currBrightness

                    if (DllCall(AC ? PowerWriteACValueIndex : PowerWriteDCValueIndex, "Ptr", 0, "Ptr", currSchemeGuid, "Ptr", BrightnessSetter._GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP(), "Ptr", BrightnessSetter._GUID_DEVICE_POWER_POLICY_VIDEO_BRIGHTNESS(), "UInt", increment, "UInt") == 0) {
                        ; PowerApplySettingChanges is undocumented and exists only in Windows 8+. Since both the Power control panel and the brightness slider use this, we'll do the same, but fallback to PowerSetActiveScheme if on Windows 7 or something
                        if (!PowerApplySettingChanges || DllCall(PowerApplySettingChanges, "Ptr", BrightnessSetter._GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP(), "Ptr", BrightnessSetter._GUID_DEVICE_POWER_POLICY_VIDEO_BRIGHTNESS(), "UInt") != 0)
                            DllCall(PowerSetActiveScheme, "Ptr", 0, "Ptr", currSchemeGuid, "UInt")
                    }
                }

                if (showOSD)
                    BrightnessSetter._ShowBrightnessOSD()
            }
            DllCall("LocalFree", "Ptr", currSchemeGuid, "Ptr")
        }
    }

    IsOnAc(ByRef acStatus)
    {
        static SystemPowerStatus
        if (!VarSetCapacity(SystemPowerStatus))
            VarSetCapacity(SystemPowerStatus, 12)

        if (DllCall("GetSystemPowerStatus", "Ptr", &SystemPowerStatus)) {
            acStatus := NumGet(SystemPowerStatus, 0, "UChar") == 1
            return True
        }

        return False
    }

    GetDefaultBrightnessIncrement()
    {
        static ret := 10
        DllCall("powrprof\PowerReadValueIncrement", "Ptr", BrightnessSetter._GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP(), "Ptr", BrightnessSetter._GUID_DEVICE_POWER_POLICY_VIDEO_BRIGHTNESS(), "UInt*", ret, "UInt")
        return ret
    }

    GetMinBrightness()
    {
        static ret := -1
        if (ret == -1)
            if (DllCall("powrprof\PowerReadValueMin", "Ptr", BrightnessSetter._GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP(), "Ptr", BrightnessSetter._GUID_DEVICE_POWER_POLICY_VIDEO_BRIGHTNESS(), "UInt*", ret, "UInt"))
                ret := 0
        return ret
    }

    GetMaxBrightness()
    {
        static ret := -1
        if (ret == -1)
            if (DllCall("powrprof\PowerReadValueMax", "Ptr", BrightnessSetter._GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP(), "Ptr", BrightnessSetter._GUID_DEVICE_POWER_POLICY_VIDEO_BRIGHTNESS(), "UInt*", ret, "UInt"))
                ret := 100
        return ret
    }

    _GetCurrentBrightness(schemeGuid, AC, ByRef currBrightness)
    {
        static PowerReadACValueIndex := DllCall("GetProcAddress", "Ptr", BrightnessSetter.hPowrprofMod, "AStr", "PowerReadACValueIndex", "Ptr")
              ,PowerReadDCValueIndex := DllCall("GetProcAddress", "Ptr", BrightnessSetter.hPowrprofMod, "AStr", "PowerReadDCValueIndex", "Ptr")
        return DllCall(AC ? PowerReadACValueIndex : PowerReadDCValueIndex, "Ptr", 0, "Ptr", schemeGuid, "Ptr", BrightnessSetter._GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP(), "Ptr", BrightnessSetter._GUID_DEVICE_POWER_POLICY_VIDEO_BRIGHTNESS(), "UInt*", currBrightness, "UInt") == 0
    }

    _ShowBrightnessOSD()
    {
        static PostMessagePtr := DllCall("GetProcAddress", "Ptr", DllCall("GetModuleHandle", "Str", "user32.dll", "Ptr"), "AStr", A_IsUnicode ? "PostMessageW" : "PostMessageA", "Ptr")
              ,WM_SHELLHOOK := DllCall("RegisterWindowMessage", "Str", "SHELLHOOK", "UInt")
        if A_OSVersion in WIN_VISTA,WIN_7
            return
        BrightnessSetter._RealiseOSDWindowIfNeeded()
        ; Thanks to YashMaster @ https://github.com/YashMaster/Tweaky/blob/master/Tweaky/BrightnessHandler.h for realising this could be done:
        if (BrightnessSetter._osdHwnd)
            DllCall(PostMessagePtr, "Ptr", BrightnessSetter._osdHwnd, "UInt", WM_SHELLHOOK, "Ptr", 0x37, "Ptr", 0)
    }

    _RealiseOSDWindowIfNeeded()
    {
        static IsWindow := DllCall("GetProcAddress", "Ptr", DllCall("GetModuleHandle", "Str", "user32.dll", "Ptr"), "AStr", "IsWindow", "Ptr")
        if (!DllCall(IsWindow, "Ptr", BrightnessSetter._osdHwnd) && !BrightnessSetter._FindAndSetOSDWindow()) {
            BrightnessSetter._osdHwnd := 0
            try if ((shellProvider := ComObjCreate("{C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}", "{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"))) {
                try if ((flyoutDisp := ComObjQuery(shellProvider, "{41f9d2fb-7834-4ab6-8b1b-73e74064b465}", "{41f9d2fb-7834-4ab6-8b1b-73e74064b465}"))) {
                     DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(flyoutDisp+0)+3*A_PtrSize), "Ptr", flyoutDisp, "Int", 0, "UInt", 0)
                    ,ObjRelease(flyoutDisp)
                }
                ObjRelease(shellProvider)
                if (BrightnessSetter._FindAndSetOSDWindow())
                    return
            }
            ; who knows if the SID & IID above will work for future versions of Windows 10 (or Windows 8). Fall back to this if needs must
            Loop 2 {
                SendEvent {Volume_Mute 2}
                if (BrightnessSetter._FindAndSetOSDWindow())
                    return
                Sleep 100
            }
        }
    }

    _FindAndSetOSDWindow()
    {
        static FindWindow := DllCall("GetProcAddress", "Ptr", DllCall("GetModuleHandle", "Str", "user32.dll", "Ptr"), "AStr", A_IsUnicode ? "FindWindowW" : "FindWindowA", "Ptr")
        return !!((BrightnessSetter._osdHwnd := DllCall(FindWindow, "Str", "NativeHWNDHost", "Str", "", "Ptr")))
    }

    _On_WM_POWERBROADCAST(wParam, lParam)
    {
        ;OutputDebug % &this
        if (wParam == 0x8013 && lParam && NumGet(lParam+0, 0, "UInt") == NumGet(BrightnessSetter._GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE()+0, 0, "UInt")) { ; PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE and a lazy comparison
            this._AC := NumGet(lParam+0, 20, "UChar") == 0
            return True
        }
    }

    _GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP()
    {
        static GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP__
        if (!VarSetCapacity(GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP__)) {
             VarSetCapacity(GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP__, 16)
            ,NumPut(0x7516B95F, GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP__, 0, "UInt"), NumPut(0x4464F776, GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP__, 4, "UInt")
            ,NumPut(0x1606538C, GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP__, 8, "UInt"), NumPut(0x99CC407F, GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP__, 12, "UInt")
        }
        return &GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP__
    }

    _GUID_DEVICE_POWER_POLICY_VIDEO_BRIGHTNESS()
    {
        static GUID_DEVICE_POWER_POLICY_VIDEO_BRIGHTNESS__
        if (!VarSetCapacity(GUID_DEVICE_POWER_POLICY_VIDEO_BRIGHTNESS__)) {
             VarSetCapacity(GUID_DEVICE_POWER_POLICY_VIDEO_BRIGHTNESS__, 16)
            ,NumPut(0xADED5E82, GUID_DEVICE_POWER_POLICY_VIDEO_BRIGHTNESS__, 0, "UInt"), NumPut(0x4619B909, GUID_DEVICE_POWER_POLICY_VIDEO_BRIGHTNESS__, 4, "UInt")
            ,NumPut(0xD7F54999, GUID_DEVICE_POWER_POLICY_VIDEO_BRIGHTNESS__, 8, "UInt"), NumPut(0xCB0BAC1D, GUID_DEVICE_POWER_POLICY_VIDEO_BRIGHTNESS__, 12, "UInt")
        }
        return &GUID_DEVICE_POWER_POLICY_VIDEO_BRIGHTNESS__
    }

    _GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE()
    {
        static GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE_
        if (!VarSetCapacity(GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE_)) {
             VarSetCapacity(GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE_, 16)
            ,NumPut(0x5D3E9A59, GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE_, 0, "UInt"), NumPut(0x4B00E9D5, GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE_, 4, "UInt")
            ,NumPut(0x34FFBDA6, GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE_, 8, "UInt"), NumPut(0x486551FF, GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE_, 12, "UInt")
        }
        return &GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE_
    }

}

BrightnessSetter_new() {
    return new BrightnessSetter()
}
```

4. Fill in the following code and add below the script

---

```
BS := new BrightnessSetter()

<increment hotkey>::BS.SetBrightness(<increment value>)
<decrement hotkey>::BS.SetBrightness(<decrement value>)
```

Example:

---

```
BS := new BrightnessSetter()

!Right::BS.SetBrightness(1)
!Left::BS.SetBrightness(-1)
```

---

`!Right` means `Alt + Right arrow key`

`!Left` means `Alt + Left arrow key`

Read AutoHotKey documentation to customize yourself.

5. Finally, you can create a shortcut for the script and place into Windows Startup folder.

[To open the folder](https://www.howtogeek.com/208224/how-to-add-programs-files-and-folders-to-system-startup-in-windows-8.1/), press `Windows+R`, enter `shell:startup`, press `Enter`.

Answer (score -1):

I use 3RVX to change my volume by 1% on windows 10. I wouldn't be surprised if their was a brightness option as well.

Comment: The question is about changing the brightness not the volume. If you're not sure that the software you've referred to cannot change brightness then it doesn't help the OP. Please edit your answer with more certain information.